# Flag to mod saying "Can be migrated to ..." but closed instead

Tags: support, migration

Recently I flagged a question which should appear in another SE site.

For example: a person asking in Portugese so it should be migrated to Stack Overflow in Portuguese.

I flagged it for moderator intervention saying that **this can be migrated to this site** (I clearly mentioned the site name instead of "this site").

But when I came across it again, Ifound that it was closed as **unclear what you are asking**

Why is the migration not done, and is it closed instead?

Can't moderators migrate to another SE site?

Comment: Was it closed by a moderator or by others? If it was closed by others, perhaps the moderators have simply not got round to it. What's your flag status?

Comment: This is the question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42812470/checar-categoria-escolhidas  Closed by 3 person and 1 of them is a mod

Comment: What is the status of your flag?

Comment: The worry is the value. Could be migrating anything and so better to close.

Comment: the status is `helpful`

Comment: If the quality of the question is unclear, we as a rule don't migrate. Stack Overflow is a *huge* site and uncontrolled migrations of dubious quality questions could easily drown target sites.

Comment: Per what Pekka said, we only migrate really good questions. If I can't read the question, I can't judge its quality, which is why I closed this one. We've been instructed in general not to migrate questions from Stack Overflow to the specific-language sites. There've been exceptions, where a staff member or moderator on one of those sites has requested something, but we close almost all of these. In our experience, if they can't find their way to the correct site, odds are they're not going to take the time to formulate a good question.

Comment: @BradLarson I mentioned one more question in the first comment to the answer. It is deleted. May I know why?

Comment: @SagarV - I refer you to [Will's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345727/flag-to-mod-saying-can-be-migrated-to-but-closed-instead#comment458180_345730).

Answer (score 13):

It was closed by regular users and a diamond moderator.

If it is in Portuguese, them most of us cannot judge its value. It could be a stellar question, but it could also be a really bad question that should be deleted. Most of us can't tell - but the odds are that it's a bad question.

We want to migrate only those questions that are welcome on the target site. If we don't know if it will be welcome, we don't migrate.

So, just because it's in Portuguese, doesn't mean the moderators are going to migrate it to Stack Overflow in Portuguese. (In fact, they can't even be certain that it is Portuguese, unless they know at least a little about the language).

If you actually speak Portuguese **and** believe it is a good question, then add this in the flag. If a moderator sees your flag and trusts your judgment, they might migrate it.

Comment: and one more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830864/adb-command-for-passwordpattern  This can be migrated to android enthusiasts. But deleted instead

Comment: I just flagged it as well - I am Brazillian so I know the question was asked in Portuguese (Brazillian Portuguese, actually) and I understood it, although I couldn't tell if it was a good question as I don't know much about PHP. It did seem like a legitimate question so I mentioned that in my flag.

Comment: @GabrielLovetro then I understand why it wasn't migrated. You, a native speaker.... can't even figure out if it's good enough or not at a glance. Why migrate crap around? A moderator (who most likely doesn't speak Portuguese) cannot know the value of that question, and can't just rely on flags. Without being sure, it's better to close than migrate

Comment: @Patrice Well, he did emphasize parts of it and it seemed like a good question. He was asking about combining two foreach to compare two lists of categories. If I knew more about PHP I would be able to better assess its usefulness... Though this is all coming from the idea that migrating a question is a simple task. You imply it isn't (or has some bad results if not done with 100% certainty), so yeah, the mods might as well close it and be done with it.

Comment: @GabrielLovetro It's not that it isn't a simple task. More along the lines of "why migrate a question if we aren't sure it's good enough to stay opened on the recipient site?" If it's a good question, by all means migrate. But, on a network that is already flooded with questions, is there a benefit in moving a Portuguese question from SO to P.SO, only to have it closed on P.SO? why not just close it on SO instead and save everyone some time? (Now... I truly don't know if the question was good. Maybe it was. I'm more talking about the generalized process here :) )

Comment: @Patrice Yeah, in this case we would need someone who knows Portuguese and PHP to assess how useful the question is. Since no one like that seems to have taken interest in the question, the mods rightfully closed it.

Comment: I installed google translate add on and so I got the question translated. And no issue on it. That's why I casted a migrate flag

Comment: @SagarV *and one more stackoverflow.com/questions/42830864/… This can be migrated to android enthusiasts. But deleted instead* that question is awful.  Please, take a break from trying to migrate stuff.  You honestly need to get a better understanding what is and is not worth migrating.

Comment: @SagarV I can't see the deleted question. But if Will tells you to get a better understanding of what should/shouldn't be migrated - I trust him. Will was a diamond moderator for years. Heed his words.

Comment: @S.L.Barth FYI: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYL8V.png

Comment: @SagarV The non-English Stack Overflow sites were created because [Google Translate was not sufficient](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/12/16/stack-overflow-in-japanese/). Don't rely on Google Translate to judge the value of a post.