# Question was closed but should be migrated

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, migration

Originally I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47509902/bivariate-beta-distribution) question in the low-quality queue, and voted to close as "unclear what you're asking"

Later, it comes up in the Reopen queue, and now that it's clarified, it's pretty apparent it's off-topic and should be migrated to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) (and comments agree)

As far as I can tell I have three kinda-bad options

- vote to reopen, and then vote to migrate if it does reopen (not likely, and not sure I could even do this)
- mod flag, knowing it will probably be declined as there is an automatic-ish process for migration (also the [Don't migrate crap rule](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345727/flag-to-mod-saying-can-be-migrated-to-but-closed-instead) might make a mod heistant to do so, even though the question seems ok now)
- move on down the queue and not worry about it

Which one is appropriate here?

Comment: Another option: suggest to the author to repost on the target site (make sure to ask them to delete the old copy once they do this).

Comment: And you *can* vote to re-open, and after it has been opened, vote to migrate, provided you haven't already cast a close vote before. You have 1 reopen vote and one close vote per post. The trick is to get other community members on board to do the same. Use a chat room that regularly covers the subject, or comments on the post, to coordinate.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters .   Did that.  Any progress on [changing your close vote reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262657/why-cant-we-change-our-close-vote-reason), which would help in this case as well?

Comment: Actually, the user already reposted at [Bivariate Beta distribution](//stats.stackexchange.com/q/315865), so I deleted the SO copy now.